# finding indices of close elements in 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 `nd arrays` where each row is a `3D` point and one array is much bigger than the other.
i.e

```
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [2.01, 5., 1.],
       [3., 3., 4.],
       [1., 4., 1.],
       [3., 6., 7.01]])

array([[3.02, 3.01, 4.0],
      [1.01, 1.99, 3.01],
      [2.98, 6.01, 7.01]])
```

And I **know** each point in the second array correspond to a point in the first array.
I would like to get the list of indices  of correspondence,

I.e for this  example it would be

```
 array([2,0,4])
```

as the first point in the second array is similar to the third point in the first array, the second point in the second array is similar to the first point in the first array, etc.

Comment: How do you get `0, 2, 4` from the two input arrays?

Comment: edited the last line, is it clear now? I'm trying to find matches "from" the second one to the first

Comment: @DsCpp Think you need to define a tolerance parameter there.

Comment: Also, would the first array always be an integer array?

Comment: edited, it's floats.

Comment: @Divakar I don't think you should delete your answer (unless you found a bug), it was a great reference for pure numpy approach to the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this efficiently with a `KDTree`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

x = np.array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [2.01, 5., 1.],
       [3., 3., 4.],
       [1., 4., 1.],
       [3., 6., 7.01]])

y = np.array([[1.01, 1.99, 3.01],
       [3.02, 3.01, 4.0],
       [2.98, 6.01, 7.01]])

result = KDTree(x).query(y)[1]

# In [16]: result                                                        
# Out[16]: array([0, 2, 4])
```

Thanks to Divakar for pointing out that `scipy` also provides a C implementation of `KDTree`, called `cKDTree`. It is 10x faster for the following benchmark:

```
x = np.random.rand(100_000, 3)
y = np.random.rand(100, 3)

def benchmark(TreeClass):
    return TreeClass(x).query(y)[1]

In [23]: %timeit q.benchmark(KDTree)                                   
322 ms ± 7.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [24]: %timeit q.benchmark(cKDTree)                                  
36.5 ms ± 763 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Would [`cKDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) be faster here?

Answer (score 2):

We can extend one of those to `3D` and then with a given tolerance parameter ( which in the given sample case seems to be something <= 0.2) compare for closeness with `np.isclose()` or `np.abs()<tolerance` and finally get `ALL` matches along last axis and get the indices -

```
In [88]: a
Out[88]: 
array([[1.  , 2.  , 3.  ],
       [2.01, 5.  , 1.  ],
       [3.  , 3.  , 4.  ],
       [1.  , 4.  , 1.  ],
       [3.  , 6.  , 7.01]])

In [89]: b
Out[89]: 
array([[3.02, 3.01, 4.  ],
       [1.01, 1.99, 3.01],
       [2.98, 6.01, 7.01]])

In [90]: r,c = np.nonzero(np.isclose(a[:,None],b, atol=0.02).all(2))

In [91]: r[c]
Out[91]: array([2, 0, 4])
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it's much closer than what I've achieved, but maybe I wasn't clear, but because I need the correspondence, I need it to be ordered (as in the edited example)

Comment: @DsCpp Edited post.